# Java: declare attribute as either Java-given or self-written type (maybe with interfaces?)

Tags: java, types, interface

I have a beginners question concerning Java.

I have a class `Thing<T>` that has an attribute "attribute".
I want the attribute to be either a `LinkedList<T>` (as given by Java) or a self-defined type named `My_Type<T>`, depending on the boolean that is given to the constructor of `Thing`. Like this:

```
public class Thing<T> {
    private ??? attribute;  // Type is not given yet. How do I do this?

    public Thing(boolean which) {
        if (which)
            attribute = new LinkedList<T>();
        else
            attribute = new My_Type<T>();
    }

   ...
}
```

`Thing` has some more methods that use `add` and `remove`, which are both implemented for `LinkedList` and `My_Type`.

How do I declare my attribute? Declaring it as Object is no option because Object does not know the methods `add` and `remove`. I thought about using interfaces, but I don't know how.

If both `LinkedList` and `My_Type` were written by me, I could let them both implement the interface `LinkedListOrMy_Type<T>` which has `add` and `remove` as methods. Then, instead of

```
    private ??? attribute;
```

I would write

```
    private LinkedListOrMy_Type<T> attribute;
```

And everything would be okay. But because I cannot modify the code of `LinkedList`, I don't know how to work around this. Any suggestions?

Making `My_Type` implement the `List` interface (given by Java) is not an option either, because there are so many methods that I would need to implement into `My_Type`. But I only want `add` and `remove`. I know it's a possible workaround - I could let `My_Type` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` in every method of List except `add` and `remove`. But I believe I could learn more about good programming if you give me a suggestions that is not as dirty as this!

Comment: Can someone tell me how to write the generics brackets into the text? I did write '<' T '>' but it doesn't show up in my question, except in the code sections. I believe it is considered some kind of command.

Comment: Use backticks `\`` to quote code, e.g. `List<T>` .

Comment: Have you considered extending `AbstractList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have one field that can be of two different types in Java; the closest you can do is have a field that is some common base type. So you have a few options.

1. Use a common base type that provides `add` and `remove`. The obvious candidate for this is `Collection`, which is implemented by `LinkedList`.
2. Use a common base type that does not provide the methods you want, but cast the object when you need to. In this case you could simply have a field of type `Object`, and each time you want to make use of your field, you have to cast it to either of the actual types.
3. Use two fields. This would seem to make more sense - having one variable of two different types is not really how variables work.
4. Wrap `LinkedList` and `MyType` in classes that have a common base type that provides the methods you need.

For instance:

```
interface WrapperThing<T> {
    void add(T item);
    void remove(T item);
}
class ListWrapperThing<T> implements WrapperThing<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    public ListWrapperThing() {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
    public void add(T item) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    public void remove(T item) {
        list.remove(item);
    }
}
class MyTypeWrapperThing<T> implements WrapperThing<T> {
    private MyType<T> my;
    public ListWrapperThing() {
        my = new MyType<T>();
    }
    public void add(T item) {
        my.add(item);
    }
    public void remove(T item) {
        my.remove(item);
    }
}
```

Then you can use a `WrapperThing<T>` variable much as if it were a variable that could (inside it) contain either a `List` or a `MyType` object.

Answer (score 1):

Going the interface route seems a good idea. Define your own interface `MyInterface` and let `MyType` implement it:

```
class MyType implements MyInterface
```

Now here's the trick: *`LinkedList` isn't final!* Use OOP to your advantage by extending the JDK class and letting it implement your interface:

```
class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList implements MyInterface
```

Let us know if this will do the trick for you...

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks for the suggestion.Still I would like to see more suggestions if possible - my main goal is learning, not solving a certain task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could implement the interface [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in your type. It is implemented by all list like classes in Java. Of course it offers more methods than you probably need, but you could implement only those you need and throw for example an not implemented exception in others.